# How to get a collection of comments from a resource in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Consider a resource: Task, which has comments enabled.

I want to get all  the comments for a task

t=Task.find(5)

t.comments yields an error.

What would be the correct way to get the collection?

Comment: what the error is? show us

Comment: it's a simple method missing.
ActiveAdmin does some polymorphic association with any "resource" (in this example, the Task model).

The issue is that it handles comments in some odd way, as there is no "comments" method available on the resource's instance.

Comment: Does Task `has_many` Comments?  Is `t` nil, because Task 5 doesn't exist?  You'll never regret giving more information than you think necessary when asking for help!

Comment: Sure Nick, but this is something in activeadmin scope, so it doesn't follow MCV standards.

Activeadmin provides "comments" for all models registered with Activeadmin.register, so there is no "has_many" declaration.

Consider: t is an instance of Task, and not nil.

Task is a model I've defined. Active admin provides a comments model by itself just by registering the model with Activeadmin.register.

If I select an instance of comments (ActiveAdmin::Comment.first), I can see the resource it's linked to by calling #resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rb
comments = ActiveAdmin::Comment.find_for_resource_in_namespace task, 'admin' # or your namespace
```

From:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/d01155f73a0e2cc27d712792270357e2b3759d05/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/views/active_admin_comments.rb#L15

Answer (score 2):

Combining the two above answers, what worked for me was inserting this into the model which contains comments (no need to make new model for comments):

```
has_many :active_admin_comments, as: :resource, class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment'
alias_method :comments, :active_admin_comments
```

Answer (score 1):

@powers' answer worked great without needing to register `ActiveAdminComment` as a new model.

To further simplify, you can create the has many relationship and just call it `comments` all in one line (without needing an alias):

```
has_many :comments, class_name: 'ActiveAdmin::Comment', as: :resource
```

Then you should be able to access comments with `task.comments`.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin creates a table for comments called "active_admin_comments". This table can be used to create a rails model, which you can create a polymorphic association from.

```
# app/models/active_admin_comment.rb
class ActiveAdminComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_admin_comments, as: :resource
end
```

Then you can do task.active_admin_comments. If you want to use task.comments, you can create an alias_method as follows:

```
# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :active_admin_comments, as: :resource
  alias_method :comments, :active_admin_comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin already provides an ActiveRecord class for that. It is defined here: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments/comment.rb

It's is `ActiveAdmin::Comment`.

So what you can do is the following:

`task = Task.last # For example
comments = ActiveAdmin::Comment.where(resource: task)`